# Is dataframe apply() really slower than dataframe itertuples()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of time + OHLC values. I want to calculate the range of the each row. My dataset has 4 million rows.

I have two approaches.

1) `df.apply`

```
df['range'] = df[['high', 'low', 'open']].apply (lambda row: (row.high 
- row.low) * (10000 / row.open), axis=1)
```

2) `df.itertuples`

```
def calc_range(df):
   displacement = []
   for row in df.itertuples():
        displacement.append((row.high - row.low) * (10000 / row.open))
   return displacement

df['range'] = calc_range(df)
```

Approach 1: 55 seconds

Approach 2: 6 seconds

I have always believed that apply is faster than iterating through the dataframe with a for loop. But it seems that I am wrong.

I am wondering two things -
1) Is there a way to optimise this apply code?
2) Is iterating faster for very large dataframes?

Thanks very much

Comment: Why not just vectorise this? `df['range'] = (df.high - df.low) * (10000 / df.open)`

Comment: I was going to add some conditions inside it later eg. ones which are dependent on what time of the day it is etc.

Comment: That doesn't preclude vectorising.

Comment: @Vazzyb You can still probably vectorize. And if you can't vectorize, you may opt for Numba, Cython, etc. This is comparing two things you shouldn't do if you care at all about performance.

Comment: Then you can accomplish that with `numpy.select`. I always understood that apply with axis=1 is essentially a for loop

Comment: No, apply is not inherently faster. Pandas is really complicated in terms of what happens under the covers, but it won't be exploiting numpy in any way with your current approach.

Comment: Ok got it. I will try and vectorise it. Thanks for your advice

Comment: [Fast, Flexible, Easy and Intuitive: How to Speed Up Your Pandas Projects](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/).  These techniques seem to be faster with larger datasets (e.g. `apply` is faster then `itertuples` if your dataset is greater 100k rows).  An example from my experience: `itertuples` was faster with 10k rows, but when the sample was 100k, `apply` was faster.  The transition, is somewhere between.